# android map overlay size

Tags: android

I've used images for my overlay and using

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);            
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);
```

It looks like the overlay size doesn't change with the zoom level.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) and not draw directly on canvas

Comment: what are the disadvantages of using overlay directly? Also will this fix my issue with the zoom level

Comment: I've changed to use itemizedoverlay. And it didn't help with the zoom level, the marker are huge ....